# Problem while loading an image for a texture

Tags: c#, textures, loading, slimdx

I have built a slideshow in slimDX and is scrolling a text at the bottom of the images. But I am running through a problem that when my new image is loaded in by the help of Texture.FromFile() function and i am giving the new image to the texture it is giving a little pause that is due to the loading of the image and moving text seems to jerky as it waits for some milli seconds when the new image is loaded. I am trying to resolve this problem by the help of a thread and also  threadPool but is not getting the right output. Can any body please help me out in this context.

Comment: You're going to have to provide some more information -- what exactly are you trying to do (i.e., code) and what exactly the incorrect output is. You probably don't want to be using the DX ThreadPool class, C#'s BackgroundWorker or Tasks library is easier to work with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you open all of the images before you start the slide show? Store them in an array of textures and then just loop through?

If not, then I would suggest using the c# threading classes Josh Petrie suggested, or using the Thread class itself, which can be easier to use than it looks.

If you are new to threading I would suggest avoiding it unless you are prepared to read up on a lot of nuances and problems unique to threading. It is certainly incredibly useful and powerful but you can end up causing a lot of problems if you're inexperienced.

Comment: You should probably mention that the logic when using threading would be to have two textures, while one is displayed, the other one is loaded in a worker thread. When you change images just swap them around.

Comment: Yes, good point. If I had the reputation I'd upvote your comment. Shame rep doesn't carry across stackexchange sites (I'm new to gamedev but more established in traditional stack overflow)